# Statement using EF Core for multiple table with same FK

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am not sure why I am receiving null values for users in PurchaseOrderHistory in the code below. I think it has to do with PurchaseOrder also containing a userID. What I don't understand is that if the UserID is the same for PurchaseOrder and PurchaseOrderHistory then it will appear. I have attached snips for clarification.

```
var purchaseOrder = await _context.PurchaseOrder
            .Include(p => p.Division)
            .Include(p => p.PaymentType)
            .Include(p => p.Status)
            .Include(p => p.Vendor)
            .Include(p => p.ItemServiceLine)
            .Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHistory)
            .Include(p => p.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

[PurchaseOrder user snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFAhW.jpg)

[PurchaseOrderHistory user snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT2BG.jpg)

Comment: what's your issue exactly, do you _never_ want the User along with the PurchaseHistory, or do you _always_ want it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that if the UserID is the same for PurchaseOrder and PurchaseOrderHistory then it will appear.

If the Change Tracker already has a User entity whose UserID matches the PurchaseOrderHistory.UserID it will "fix up" the navigation property.

Comment: this is it. If OP wants to always include users for purchase history, they need to do `.Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHistory).ThenInclude(poh => poh.User)`

Comment: and if OP _never_ wants to have PurchaseOrderHistory.User populated, then... I don't know

Comment: Then you just do not show it. Which also may mean removing them if you auto-serialize this to external. This fixup is seriously a bug (though likely one of those "work as designed, the designer just should be fired") because if I do not tell it to expand, then I do not want it expanded. Fixup should know the expansion paths.

Answer (score 1):

You include `PurchaseOrder`'s `User`, not `PurchaseOrderHistory`'s. If both user ids are the same, relationship fixup will also populate `PurchaseOrderHistory`'s `User` because it's attached to the context.

What you intended to do is:

```cs
var purchaseOrder = await _context.PurchaseOrder
            .Include(p => p.Division)
            .Include(p => p.PaymentType)
            .Include(p => p.Status)
            .Include(p => p.Vendor)
            .Include(p => p.ItemServiceLine)
            .Include(p => p.User)
            .Include(p => p.PurchaseOrderHistory)
                .ThenInclude(poh => poh.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```